# Laravel -request fails mySQL update

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, datatable

The question is this: There is a table with forms in each row. Created with dataTables:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "targets": -1,
    "defaultContent": "<form action='start-data-submit'> <input  name=\"prod_barcode\" />"
},
{
    "data": null,
    "targets": -1,
    "defaultContent": " <input name=\"prod_quantity\"/>"
},
{
    "data": null,
    "targets": -1,
    "defaultContent": " <input name=\"prod_price\" />"
},
{
    "data": "id",
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false
},
{
    "data": "updated_at",
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": false
},
{
    "data": null,
    "defaultContent": " <button name=\"submit\" >Update</button> </form>"
}
```

on click in the form, the following is processed:

```
$('#start-data tbody').on('click', 'button', function () { //click update
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var data = table.row(row).data().id;
            var info = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_barcode']").val();
            var infoq = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_quantity']").val();
            var infop = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_price']").val();
            var url = "start-data-submit/" + "id=" + data + "&prod_barcode=" + info + "&prod_quantity=" + infoq + "&prod_price=" + infop + " ";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
```

`route`:

```
Route::get('start-data-submit/{id}&{prod_barcode}&{prod_quantity}&{prod_price}','StartDataController@update')
```

`controller`:

```
 public function prodview(Request $request)
    {
        $timestamps = Carbon::today();
        $prod_barcode = $request->route('prod_barcode');
        $prod_quantity = $request->route('prod_quantity');
        $prod_price = $request->route('prod_price');
        $uid = $request->route('id');

        DB::table('products')
            ->where('id', $uid)
            ->update(
                [
                    'updated_at' => $timestamps,
                    'prod_barcode' => $prod_barcode,
                    'prod_quantity' => $prod_quantity,
                    'prod_price' => $prod_price
                ]
            );
    }
```

It seems that everything is visible - the variables have the necessary values, but update does not happen, it does not give an error.

```
var_dump($timestamps,$prod_barcode,$prod_quantity,$prod_price,$uid);
```

issues:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#344 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-07-17 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } string(14) "prod_barcode=2" string(15) "prod_quantity=4" string(13) "prod_price=78" string(7) "id=4680"
```

where else to dig?

Comment: Try using `Carbon::now()` for `$timestamps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the values you are posting in your request also contain the column names in them.

You have them as:

```
$prod_barcode = "prod_barcode=2";
$prod_quantity = "prod_quantity=4";
$prod_price = "prod_price=78";
$uid = "id=4680";
```

But want them as:

```
$prod_barcode = 2;
$prod_quantity = 4;
$prod_price = 78;
$uid = 4680;
```

Your main issue here is you are using the route parameters like they are GET parameters. They are not the same thing. A route parameter is part of the url, ie)`users/{user_id}/posts` where `user_id` is the route parameter. The GET parameters are the query string, like `users/posts?user_id=1`.

You access route parameters, `$request->route('user_id')` and you access query string parameters like `$request->query('user_id')`.

You can access your data properly like this using the query string:

```
$prod_barcode = $request->query('prod_barcode');
$prod_quantity = $request->query('prod_quantity');
$prod_price = $request->query('prod_price');
$uid = $request->query('id');
```

But the url in your js is wrong, and needs to be:

```
var url = "start-data-submit?"...(Rest the same)
```

Or you can do this (which is bad imo):

```
$prod_barcode = explode('=', $request->route('prod_barcode'))[0];
$prod_quantity = explode($request->route('prod_quantity'))[0];
$prod_price = explode($request->route('prod_price'))[0];
$uid = explode($request->route('id'))[0];
```

For a route parameter based solution, in your JS you would do:

```
var data = table.row(row).data().id;
var info = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_barcode']").val();
var infoq = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_quantity']").val();
var infop = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_price']").val();
var url = "start-data-submit/" + data + "/" + info + "/" + infoq + "/" + infop;
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

And in your routes file:

```
Route::get('start-data-submit/{id}/{prod_barcode}/{prod_quantity}/{prod_price}','StartDataController@update')
```

Which allows you in your controller to do:

```
public function prodview(int $prod_barcode, int $prod_quantity, int $prod_price, int $uid)
{
    $timestamp = Carbon::today();

    DB::table('products')
      ->where('id', $uid)
      ->update([
          'updated_at' => $timestamp,
          'prod_barcode' => $prod_barcode,
          'prod_quantity' => $prod_quantity,
          'prod_price' => $prod_price
      ]);
}
```

To solve your event binding issue you can use:

Unbind existing event handlers before the table is redrawn:

```
$('#start-data').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    $('.table-btn-class').each(function (idx, el) {
       el.prop("onclick", null).off("click");
    });
});
```

Then after a new page is redrawn, bind all of the handlers like so:

```
$('#start-data').on('draw.dt', function () {
    $('.table-btn-class').each(function (idx, el) {
        el.on("click", function (el) {
            var row = el.closest('tr');
            var data = table.row(row).data().id;
            var info = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_barcode']").val();
            var infoq = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_quantity']").val();
            var infop = table.row(row).$("input[name='prod_price']").val();
            var url = "start-data-submit/" + "id=" + data + "&prod_barcode=" + info + "&prod_quantity=" + infoq + "&prod_price=" + infop + " ";
            $(location).attr('href', url);
       });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: now I don't understand at all at what stage to assign the correct value to a variable for a query into a table

Comment: @Ing.VakulinOleg Please see my updated answer with more details.

Comment: I am very grateful to you - it works. But now I am faced with another problem - JS sends only when filling in the input, only the topmost line.

Comment: In this case, on any page ONLY the top line. More than 10 thousand records

Comment: Your issue is that you are using ```$('#start-data tbody').on('click', 'button', function () { 
var row = $(this).closest('tr')```

Comment: @Ing.VakulinOleg I have updated the answer to solve your table binding issues. However I would recommend you open a new question about this, so it is more helpful to other users, and I will move the answer there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, I was unable to implement this code. Error - no function. I will understand further

Comment: @Ing.VakulinOleg Well at least accept the answer please, since it solved the issue stated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public function prodview(Request $request)
    {
        $timestamps = Carbon::today();
        $prod_barcode = $request->route('prod_barcode');
        $prod_quantity = $request->route('prod_quantity');
        $prod_price = $request->route('prod_price');
        $uid = $request->route('id');

        DB::table('products')
            ->where('id', $uid)
            ->update(
                [
                    'updated_at' => $timestamps,
                    'prod_barcode' => $prod_barcode,
                    'prod_quantity' => $prod_quantity,
                    'prod_price' => $prod_price
                ]
            );
    }
```

For fixing above issues, you can try below things:

**Method 1:**

```
   //add products model on the top
    use App\Products;

  $products = Products::where('id', $uid);
  $products->fill($request->input())->save();
```

**Method 2:**

```
     use Carbon\Carbon;
     use App\Products; 

        Products::where('id', $uid)
        ->update(
            [
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'prod_barcode' => $request->prod_barcode,
                'prod_quantity' => $request->prod_quantity,
                'prod_price' => $request->prod_price
            ]
        );
```

Instead of `$request->prod_barcode`, you can also use `$request->get('prod_barcode')`.

Hope this works in your case!!